# Outlook Quick Access Toolbar does not have Styles commands

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016

I am trying to add some frequently used **Styles** commands to Outlook quick access toolbar when I am writing an email. In Outlook, there are two way to create a new email.

1. Right from the main Outlook window (when you reply to someone's email) - The custom quick access toolbar is called **OLKExplorer**.

[image]

2. A new Email Window (When you create a new email) - The custom quick access toolbar is called **OLKMailItem**

[image]

I would like the **Quick Access toolbar** to be the same for both. However, all the **Styles** command are missing for the **Option 1**.

[image]

See the screenshot below,

[image]

[image]

I even tried to export the customizations from a New Window and import in Outlook window, and it gave me the following error.

[image]

[image]

I am sorry, if it sounds convoluted. I tried to add as many screenshots to show what I am asking.

Can someone help me get the **Styles** commands in the Main Outlook Window's **Quick Access toolbar**?

Answer (score 1):

This is by design that you cannot choose Style when directly composing emails in Reading Pane. This option is available when you compose email in a separate Email window.

Because that's not supported so you cannot add "Style" option to Main Outlook Window's QuickAccess Toolbar.

Comment: I suppose, this is the issue. It is by "design". I wonder why would MS have not thought of allowing the same set of options for composing emails either in Reading pane or a separate window?

Comment: I think you could submit feedback to Outlook UserVoice forum: https://outlook.uservoice.com/

Comment: @Gifcrazy – maybe because that would need separate dialog window for selecting styles? (Expensive and unnecessary, no one would open it if the gallery is already on the menu...) You can switch to full window by pressing **Ctrl+O** (Open) anytime during composing so maybe the entire thing is not so big issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your message is HTML,  then in the New Message, Quick Access, More Commands, and then in the Window that comes up (as you showed above), where it says Popular Commands, switch to All Commands (important step) and Styles is in the All Commands list. I just added it.

It may not show up in a Text format reply. I was certain to ensure HTML

Comment: How do you make sure your message is in html? BTW, I just checked, In the Outlook options, under Mail, I have set Compose messages in 'HTML' format. Also, the Styles command show up in the New Email Window, but not in the mail Outlook window. Please check my screenshots. Thank  you.

Comment: In a New Mail (or Reply), click on Format Text and if HTML it will show as selected. To ensure for New Emails, close Outlook, re-open, Options, Mail options and set to HTML.  Now Styles only affect New Mail so the option is not in the Main Outlook Window (I double checked that)